# How to understand the "Currying" in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Assume there is a function called "smallerc"

```
    smallerc :: Integer -> (Integer->Integer)
    smallerc x y = if x <=y then x else y
```

Why not declare the function by using:

```
    smallerc :: (Integer -> Integer) ->Integer
```

Thank you!

Comment: Note that you could tuple the inputs if you so desired: `smallerc :: (Integer, Integer) -> Integer; smallerc (x, y) = ...`. Occasionally people do this to make Haskell function calls look a little more like function calls in other languages, however, it is unidiomatic Haskell.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The key to understanding currying is to understand that there is no such thing as a function with more than one argument. *Every* function in haskell has exactly one argument. But because of the right-associative properties of the `->` operator, that's not immediately clear.

When you see this:

```
Integer -> Integer -> Integer
```

It is equivalent to this:

```
Integer -> (Integer -> Integer)
```

In both cases, the function takes an `Integer` and *returns a function*. (The function returned is one that takes an `Integer` and returns an `Integer`.) So this might be something like a simple mathematical operation; it takes an `Integer` (let's say 5) and returns a function that takes another `Integer` (5 again) and adds it to the first one, and returns the result (10).

But when you do this:

```
(Integer -> Integer) -> Integer
```

You've created something very different -- a function that *takes* a function and returns an `Integer`. This could also be a way of implementing a mathematical function; but instead of taking an `Integer` as the first argument, it takes the mathematical operation itself! So for example, say you pass to this function a function that adds 5 to whatever is passed to it. This function then passes `5` to *that* function, and returns the result (10).

Comment: A concrete example of a function of type `(Integer -> Integer) -> Integer` would be `supplyFive f = f 5`.  His specific example would then be `supplyFive (+5)`, which evaluates to `10`.

Answer (score 1):

The Arrow operator is right-associative.
Meaning, your first example would be a function taking an `Integer` and returning `Integer -> Integer` a function taking an Integer and returning an Integer.
In contrast your second example would be a function taking an `Integer -> Integer` function and returning an `Integer`.

Comment: And the latter function can't do much except returning a constant integer and applying its parameter to a constant int. `smallerc` cannot exist with that signature.

Comment: Well it could actually be `fix`, but I always felt, that `fix*` was a bit like cheating.

Comment: @delnan The latter function can do loads of things! It could iterate the input function 5 times on zero, then take the result and iterate the input function *that* many times on the 101st prime number, and then return that result. It could count the number of inputs with absolute value less than ten thousand for which the output is even. It could count the number of iterations required for the input function to either loop or exceed 10000 in absolute value. When a large concrete type like `Integer` is involved, there are really quite a lot of options.

Comment: Indeed, if you instead had to adhere to the type signature `foo :: (a -> a) -> a`, then all you could really do is `foo f = let x = f x in x` or `foo f = f undefined`.