# A better way to understand the logic of nested functions (Currying)

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I am learning [Jason Hickey's Introduction to Objective Caml](http://www.cs.caltech.edu/courses/cs134/cs134b/book.pdf). Just have a question about **nested functions (currying)**.

there is a existing question [How to understand the "Currying" in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357668/how-to-understand-the-currying-in-haskell), but I guess I am seeking for the answer of slightly different question.

---

It says that we can write `let sum = fun i j -> i + j;;` as `let sum = fun i -> fun j -> i + j;;`

My question is simple:

**Can I understand the above definition in this way: `let sum = fun i -> i + fun j -> j;;`?**

I know it won't pass the compiler, but I just try to map this kind of `OCaml function definition` to the `mathematics functions`.

In my above imagination, we can write the function easily in mathematics, `f(i) = i + g(j); and g(j) = j`.

**Should I always do this kind of logic mapping for easy understanding?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your imagination is not really correct: `f(i) = i + g(j)` doesn't mean much as `j` is undefined here.

A correct way to understand `fun i j -> foo` is to consider it some convenient syntactic sugar for the more explicit notation `fun i -> fun j -> foo`.

All the definitions below are exactly equivalent :

```
let sum i j = i + j
let sum i = fun j -> i + j
let sum = fun i -> (fun j -> i + j)
let sum = fun i -> fun j -> i + j
let sum = fun i j -> i + j

let sum i =
  let add_i = fun j -> i + j in
  add_i
```

Mathematically this could be written (i ↦ (j ↦ i+j)), as an element of
the function space (ℕ → (ℕ → ℕ)).

Answer (score 1):

OCaml functions can be directly mapped to and from mathematical notation. However, you need to realize that mathematical notation is ambiguous. There is not a clear distinction between the value of the function, `f(i)`, on a particular value `i`, and the function `f` itself. Often one writes `f(i)` when one means the function `f` itself. ("Let us consider a function f(i)=i+1... This function is ...") To write correct code in OCaml, you have to see clearly whether you are working with a function itself or with the value of a function.

When you say in mathematical notation, "Consider the function `f(i,j)=i+g(j) where g(j)=j`, you are writing the values of the functions. In OCaml, this is translated to

```
  let f i j = 
       let g j = j in 
       i + g j;;
```

or

```
  let f = 
     let g = fun j -> j 
     in
     fun i j -> i + g j;;
```

If you are trying to write `let sum = fun i -> i + fun j -> j;;`, then in mathematical notation you are saying "Consider the function `sum` such that `sum(i) = i + g`, where g is a function defined by `g(j)=j`." This is mathematically incorrect: you cannot add an *integer value* `i` and a *function* `g`. You can only add an integer `i` and the *value* of the function `g` on some other integer `j`. The expression "`i+g`" is undefined, strictly speaking. Either you wanted to write `i + g(i)`, or `i+g(j)`, but not `i+g`. This is so in mathematics, and this is so in OCaml.